# Invalid initializer?

Tags: c, winapi

```
01 #include <stdio.h>
02 #include <stdlib.h>
03 #include <windows.h>
04 
05 HANDLE StdHandle;
06 
07 int  RGBI (int Red, int Green, int Blue, int Intensified);
08 int Set_Color (int RGB_Fore, int RGB_Back);
09 
10 int main (void)
11 {
12   StdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
13   Set_Color(RGBI(0,1,0,1), RGBI(0,0,1,1));
14   char Str [8] = "Great.\n";
15   printf("%s", Str);
16   system("pause>nul");
17   CONSOLE_FONT_INFO FONT;
18   GetCurrentConsoleFont(StdHandle, FALSE, &FONT);
19   COORD Fontsize = GetConsoleFontSize(StdHandle, FONT.nFont);
20   return 0;
21 }
22 
23 int RGBI (int Red, int Green, int Blue, int Intensified)
24 {
25   return (Intensified*8 + Red*4 + Green*2 + Blue);
26 }
27 
28 int Set_Color (int RGB_Fore, int RGB_Back)
29 {
30   SetConsoleTextAttribute(StdHandle, RGB_Fore + RGB_Back*16);
31   return 0;
32 }
```

TDM-GCC reported

```
>mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -c "main.c" -o "main.o"

main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:18:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'GetCurrentConsoleFont' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   GetCurrentConsoleFont(StdHandle, FALSE, &FONT);
   ^
main.c:19:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'GetConsoleFontSize' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   COORD Fontsize = GetConsoleFontSize(StdHandle, FONT.nFont);
   ^
main.c:19:3: error: invalid initializer
main.c:19:9: warning: unused variable 'Fontsize' [-Wunused-variable]
   COORD Fontsize = GetConsoleFontSize(StdHandle, FONT.nFont);
         ^
```

Why? Should I update `windows.h`?

Where to download the latest version of the `windows.h`?

Thanks.

Comment: I would grab the latest version of mingw64, that function should be defined by including `<windows.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to define the minimum Windows version so add this before the `#include <windows.h>`

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x500
```

[MSDN says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> To compile an application that uses this function, define _WIN32_WINNT
>   as 0x0500 or later. For more information, see Using the Windows
>   Headers.

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia Your code compiled without any issues for me using the MinGW64 distribution from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html (with GCC 4.8.2), so the issue might be in your MinGW installation.

Comment: I know the reason! The `wincon.h` in MinGW64 and MinGW32 are different. In MinGW32, GetConsoleFontSize() is undefined.

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia That's odd, but I'm happy your issue got solved :)

Comment: Can I replace MinGW32's wincon.h with MinGW64's wincon.h ?

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia I honestly have no idea. Give it a try and find out :) I would imagine the api for console services is the same for 32-bit och 64-bit though, but I don't know.